# how to use url rewriter.net to auto rewrite urls

Tags: asp.net, urlrewriter.net

i am trying to rewrite any URL that match this pattern:

```
~/Ahmed
~/Name
```

to this:

```
~/User/Ahmed/Ahmed.aspx
~/User/Name/Name.aspx
```

and i can write them individually but what i am trying to do is detect any URL that look like `"~/User/Ahmed/Ahmed"` and auto rewrite them to this `"Ahmed"`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you're using the UrlRewritingNet library, not UrlRewriter? The former is suggested over the latter.

However, in either you can use a regex:

```
"~/User/([^/\\]+)/\1.aspx"  ->  "~/$1" //For ".aspx" in the URL
"~/([A-Za-z]+)" to "~/User/$1/$1.aspx" //For /Name in the URL.
```

Note the ([^/\]+) means any set of characters without slashes,
and "\1" is a backreference to the previous capture, that ensures the name is an exact duplicate. Note that you should enable "ignore case" if you want to support "/User/ahmed/Ahmed.aspx" and not just "/User/Ahmed/Ahmed.aspx".

Comment: i tried this`<rewrite url="~/$1" to="~/User/([^/\\]+)/\1.aspx" />` but got resource not found

Comment: You've got them backwards. Switch url and to.

Comment: Unless your question is backwards. Does the URL in the browser end in ".aspx"?

Comment: yes you are right my question is backwards (very sorry) its fixed now

Comment: Yes, but now it doesn't make sense, because you won't be able to have any pages - they'll be 'names'.

Comment: i just made the url look like this ~/User/Name and now it works thanks very much

Comment: but now it rewrite images url so is there anyway to stop from rewriting these

Comment: `<rewrite url="~/User/([A-Za-z]+)" to="~/User/$1/$1.aspx" />` this is the full code

Comment: <rewrite url="~/User/([A-Za-z]+)$" to="~/User/$1/$1.aspx" />

Comment: when i tried this i got directory listing not the actual page

Comment: incoming url `elwazefa.com/User/Name` to be rewrited to `elwazefa.com/User/Name/Name.aspx`

Comment: I don't have access to your environment or files, so I can't really help you debug what you're doing wrong. I suggest you start by studying regular expressions a bit, then experimenting with different URLs to see happens. http://www.regular-expressions.info/